# Does a cadlag function reach its supremum?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^+$ be right-continuous with left limits (cadlag). Let $M:=\sup_{0\leq x\leq 1}f(x)$ be its supremum. Does the function reach its maximum? That is, does there exist $s\in[0,1]$ such that $f(s)=M$?

Comment: What if $f(x)=x\cdot1\{x<0.5\}$?  $M=0.5$; however, there is no $x$ s.t. $f(x)=0.5$...