# If $x(t)$ is right-continuous and has left-limits $x(t-)$, then $t\mapsto x(t-)$ is left-continuous

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, continuity, levy-processes

Let $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a<b$,  $(E,d)$ be a metric space and $x:[a,b]\to E$. Assume that, for all $t\in[a,b]$, $x$ has a left-sided limit $x(t-)$ and a right-sided limit $x(t+)$, where $x(a-):=x(a)$ and $x(b+):=x(b)$.

We can easily show$^1$ that $x$ is bounded.

> How can we show that
>
> 1. $x$ even attains its infimum and supremum (maybe assuming that $x$ is either right- or left-continuous)?
> 2. If $x$ is right-continuous, then it is uniformly right-continuous?
> 3. If $x$ is right-continuous, then $$x^-(t):=x(t-)\;\;\;\text{for }t\in[a,b]$$ is left-continuous?

My finial goal is to show (3.), but I think that we need (2.) for that and it seems to me that we need (1.) to show (2.).

I've actually no idea how we can show (1.), since the analogue statement for continuous functions on compact spaces depends on the fact that the image space is compact as well. This can obviously not applied here ... However, I guess we need to assume that $x$ is at least either right- or left-continuous, but even then the former result cannot be applied. So, how do we need to argue?

---

$^1$ Assuming the contrary, there is a $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\subseteq[a,b]$ with $$d(x(t_0),x(t_n))\ge n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N.$$ Since $[a,b]$ is sequentially compact, $t_{n_k}\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}t$ for some increasing $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ for some $t\in[a,b]$. By passing to another subsequence, if necessary, we can assume that $(t_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is monotonic. Assume that it is nondecreasing. Then, $$d(x(t_{n_k}),x(t-))\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}0$$ and hence $$\infty\xleftarrow{k\to\infty}n_k\le d(x(t_0),x(t_{n_k}))\le d(x(t_0),x(t-))+d(x(t_{n_k},x(t-))\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}d(x(t_0),x(t-));$$ which is impossible.

Comment: You ultimate question (3) is answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373293/showing-that-the-left-hand-limit-function-is-left-continuous, therefore I have deleted my answer. Note that the right-continuity of the function is not needed for that conclusion.

Comment: (1) is wrong: Consider $f(x) = x$ for $-1 < x < 1$ and $f(-1) = f(1) = 0$.

Comment: @MartinR It is claimed in the book of Applebaum (bullet point (4) on p. 118): https://books.google.com/books?id=q7eDUjdJxIkC&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=applebaum+%22Many+useful+properties+of+continuous+functions+continue+to+hold+for+%22&source=bl&ots=AtdsqwzTJn&sig=ACfU3U1RY6gBBFHhKIBaVMIrmmXcWABIXA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUkJiUhsrzAhVnS_EDHdeIDIUQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=applebaum%20%22Many%20useful%20properties%20of%20continuous%20functions%20continue%20to%20hold%20for%20%22&f=false. Am I missing something?

Comment: That is about càdlàg functions, which have left-limits at every point and are right-continuous. – So what I meant is that (1) is wrong without additional assumptions.

Comment: @MartinR Ah, no, that's why I've added the sentence in the braces. I already thought that we might need to assume that it is right or left-continuous. Do you have a reference for (1.) then? Unfortunately, the question has been closed, while the "duplicate" only answers (3.) ...

Comment: (3) is the problem from the question title, and also what you called the “final goal” therefore I agree with the closure as a duplicate. As you describe it, (1) and (2) were only a mean in your attempt to prove (3). – I would suggest to start a new question about (1) if necessary.

Comment: Btw, $f(x) = x$ for $-1 \le 0 < 1$, $f(1) = 0$ is a càdlàg function if I see it correctly, but it does not attain the supremum. So the statement in the book could be wrong. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1333414/42969.